# Android expandable listview

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview

in an android expandable listview, i need to make thechildren displayed, only on pressing the expand collapse nodes..ie; i do notwant to show the children on pressing the row of the expandable listview..how can i accomplish it?

Regards,
Rony

Comment: Hi, Can anyone kindly help? I am stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the expandable listview always expand without click group? 
 You can check this question [How to keep ExpandableListView in expanded status?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988337) and [Expandable ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6849013) .