# Expandable ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using expandableListView for UI design, so I am wondering for Android expandable listview, is there a way to allow only one list item expanded, i.e. when you click and expand an item, all other items are collapsed automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Use answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-in-expandablelistview

Comment: I put some code in another question that does what you're looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-in-expandablelistview/4315162#4315162

Answer (score 10):

When you click one item you could loop through the rest and collapse each one except for the one you just clicked...

```
list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        int len = mAdapter.getGroupCount();

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if(i != groupPosition) {
                list.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as kieran suggested, or if you only have one open at a time, you could just keep track of which one you last clicked. You could do this by declaring `int lastclicked` in the class body then in the listener as Korean suggested, put `list.collapseGroup(lastclicked)`

I would give a code example, but I'm on my mobile. Sorry.

But I just personally prefer the lastclicked method of doing it than using a for loop. It seems more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all implement OnGroupExpandListener in your Activity that will allow you to add its default method, and after add that default method you need to do like this:

```
@Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int len = expadapter.getGroupCount();           
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(i!=groupPosition)
            {
                expandlst.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }
```