# Expand all children in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to expand all children while the expandable list view is populated.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
int count = viewAdapted.getGroupCount();
for (int position = 1; position <= count; position++)
    listView.expandGroup(position - 1);
```

which is pretty ugly.
Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849013/expandable-listview

Comment: Apparently this is the only solution right now. Hoped there is some attribute or similar.

Comment: Of course (position <= count) ... copy past typo

Comment: @Drejc: could you pick the correct answer?

Comment: There was ... but it was deleted

Comment: What do you mean when "It was deleted"? Could you pick it at now?

Answer (score 79):

You can expand it in getGroupView in your custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    return v;
}
```

Gluck!

Comment: this makes them unclickable

Comment: @DavidLawson: yep, my sollution is fixed-expand them. If you wana expand them and they are clickable, you have to handle that where ExpandableListView is created, like Drejc's sollution.

Answer (score 39):

putting this code on your adapter will make the expandlist to stay open, and disables its closing function.

```
ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
```

this may be a little work around but works how it should be. It opens all group ( at start ) and can be close any time

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < groupList.getCount(); i++ ) {
    groupList.expandGroup(i);
 }
```

NOTE : 
put this code after setting adapter on your expandable view, or else it may cause error. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesnt matter where you put this code, before or after `setAdapter`. But you should put that after your set your data for adapter. This makes sens if you sets adapter and then loads your data  over a network

Answer (score 8):

first  fill the adapter than put this code in your oncreate method

```
   int count = adapter.getGroupCount();
                for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) 
                    listView.expandGroup(i);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Expanding all groups**

```
for(int i=0; i < myAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    myExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
```

**if you wish to make them unCollapseable.**

```
myExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int  groupPosition, long id) { 
    return true; 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the responses listed but i found that i can use the [**getGroupCount()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupCount()) method to get the number of groups.

Using this method i can iterate and expand every group of my `ExpandableListView`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myExpandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount(); i++) {
      //Expand group
      myExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
 }
```