# without clicking on Parent view,How to enable the parant view with childs within the Expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using ExpandableListView .I got some Examples .Here is when i am clicking on Parent childs are enable. Can any one suggest that to enable all childs along with parent fields while open the page.

Comment: do you want to expand all child views when you load list?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873345/expand-all-children-in-expandable-list-view @Sai

Comment: while scrolling expanble List data is changing constantly. can any one suggest that to maintain constant data in list.