# expandablelistview always open(android)

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an `expandablelistview` and if click in the header I don't want `expandablelistview` to hide its children elements, like this:

[image: Don't hide expandablelistview's children elements]

My xml:

```
android:id="@+id/exListView"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand all children in expandable list view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873345/expand-all-children-in-expandable-list-view)

Comment: @DerGol...lum thanks for answer, i use this `View v = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);` and i have error `abstract method getgroupview cantnot be accessed directory`

Comment: `abstract method getgroupview cantnot be accessed directory`... do you mean `abstract method getGroupView() cannot be accessed directly`?

Comment: @DerGol...lum yes it is

Comment: Well, some code is required.