# RecyclerView with another RecyclerView/ListView inside each individual item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of recipes in my database. Each recipe contains a title, and a list of ingredients like so:

[image]

This then needs to be properly displayed in an android device in a recyclerview. So far, in my *activity_main.xml* I have created a recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:background="#f1f1f1"
  android:gravity="center">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewRecipes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the custom recyclerview list item looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cornered_background"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRecipeTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewIngredients"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvRecipeTitle">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see from the code above, I then have another recyclerview for the various ingredients inside each recipe item. I am convinced that this is not the right way to go about this. How would I efficiently display the list of ingredients inside each recyclerview item?

Comment: Have you tried [Chip component](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) . I am not sure whether its an `AdapterView` or not have a look.

Comment: I think it is good if you don't go with material design/

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView

Answer (score 0):

Using ExpandableListview with groups always expanded can help you i guess.
[Expand all children in expandable list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873345/expand-all-children-in-expandable-list-view)