# Expandable listview's child gets recalled again

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a expandable listview.on expanding a group i am getting child views with a footer which has an edit text.Now when i write something in that edit text and when i scroll up/down the text written inside it gets blanked.So  i have followed this link [collasping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849013/)

expandable-listview it works but that at one time i am expanding one group but how to keep the values intact even when scrolling and clear its when when group gets collapsed..any help please.
heres my childview code

```
public View getChildView(int gposition, int childposition, boolean isLastChild, View arg3, ViewGroup arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();


    if(childposition == 0)return arg3 = inf.inflate(R.layout.child_header, null);

    if(isLastChild){
        arg3 = inf.inflate(R.layout.child_footer, null);
    }
```

in this child footer i have an edittext.

Comment: can you post some of your code please?

Comment: i will post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/), it is quite simple, and explain quite well the solution to your problem (it's not am expandablelistview, but the theory is the same).

The core problem is:

> You can’t save anything on `ListView` Item. You must need to handle another data-source 
>   that maintain your changes in `ListView`’s item.

This is the part of the code that do the job:

```
 //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
 holder.caption.setText(myItems.get(position).caption);
 holder.caption.setId(position);

 //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
 holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                  final int position = v.getId();
                  final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                  myItems.get(position).caption = Caption.getText().toString();
            }
       }
 });
```

You just have to create a `myItems` that is not a simple list but a `List<List>` or a `Map<String, List>`.

For the collapsing of the group take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314777/programmatically-collapse-a-group-in-expandablelistview?lq=1), i think it's more efficient than the loop one

Also take a look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) it will improve a lot design and performance of your listview/expandablelistview